# android push server instance to application

Tags: android, web-services, push-notification

I am new to android and I have a small doubt. Like

Is it possible to push a server instance to application ? Can do it with gcm notification. At that time is it possible to do some actions if the application is live / currently using and if doesn't make a notification .

In first case no need to show any notification.

Please advise
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> At that time is it possible to do some actions if the application is live / currently using and if doesn't make a notification .

You can accomplish this using an event bus, where your GCM receiving code publishes the event on the event bus, then detects if nothing picked up that event and displays the `Notification`.

The following projects demonstrate this basic pattern (though triggered by `AlarmManager` instead of GCM), using:

- [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager)
- [Square's Otto](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/Otto)
- [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot)

Comment: is this event bus a third party ?

Comment: @ramesh: Square's Otto and greenrobot's EventBus are third-party libraries. `LocalBroadcastManager` is part of the Android Support package.